# FragmentManager is null after creating Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmentmanager

My problem is that after creating a new `Fragment`, its `FragmentManager` is sometimes `null` when setting it as the current item in my `ViewPager`.
In other words, this causes a `NullPointerException` in `ViewPager`'s `setCurrentItem()` because it makes a reference to the fragment's `FragmentManager`.

The 1st time I execute the following code, the FragmentManager is almost never null (but adding print statements sometimes changes that behavior), and it always crashes the 2nd time due to the FragmentManager being null.

```
Fragment fragment = PostsFragment.newInstance( some_string_params );
int position = pager_adapter.addFragment( fragment );

Log.i( "MY_TAG", fragment.getFragmentManager() ); //sometimes null !!!!!

view_pager.setCurrentItem( position ); //internal NullPointerException
```

It almost seems like the Fragment is still being set up in the background, and it's just not ready in time to be used.  How can I fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is my `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    private final FragmentManager fragment_manager;
    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter( FragmentManager manager )
    {
        super( manager );
        this.fragment_manager = manager;
    }

    public int addFragment( Fragment fragment )
    {
        fragments.add( fragment );
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        return fragments.size() - 1;
    }

    public void pop()
    {
        int index = getCount() - 1;
        Fragment fragment = fragments.remove( index );

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragment_manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.remove( fragment );
        transaction.commit();
        fragment_manager.executePendingTransactions(); //execute the commit synchronously

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem( int position )
    {
        return fragments.get( position );
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(android.support.v4.app.Fragment)' on a null object reference
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1175)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:608)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:551)
at fragments.CategoryActivityFragment.onCategoryClicked(CategoryActivityFragment.java:56)
at adapters.CategoriesAdapter$1.onClick(CategoriesAdapter.java:84)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5207)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21168)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: could you provide some more code? to instantiate the fragments I override getItem in the FragmentPagerAdapter class.

Comment: @JohnathonHavens 
What exactly would you like to see? 
The snippet I posted so far is pretty isolated inside of a `View.OnClickListener` which is attached to several buttons representing categories. So I click a button, that code executes to create the fragment and switch to it with the `ViewPager`.  As for my `addFragment()` method, it just adds the fragment to a `LinkedList` and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: I'm just trying to see how your class extending `FragmentPagerAdapter` is defined, when I use the pager it's usually in tandem with a `TabLayout` to select the other pages or changed via swiping. What is the stack trace when `setCurrentItem` is called?

Comment: @JohnathonHavens
I added the class extending FragmentPagerAdapter and the stacktrace.

Comment: any reason why you don't create the fragment inside Adapter? for example in `getItem(position)` you can check what type of fragment need to be generated and then return the type of fragment based on that type.
I feel, your code is not the best way to use FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 1):

You probably should let the class create the fragment for you, there's no need to store the fragments in a list.

```
private final String[] categories = {"cat1", "cat2", "cat3"};
private final String[] titles = {"category 1", "category 2", "category 3"};
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return categories.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PostsFragment.newInstance(categories[position]);
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return titles[position];
  }
}
```

Then the fragment is created automatically when you switch positions.